# Is it possible to use ssh-copy-id once password based logins are disabled?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

Is it possible to use ssh-copy-id once password based logins are disabled? Otherwise, is there an utility for adding an authorized public key to a user or should I edit the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file manually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have multiple ssh keys and already have one set up for authentication on the server or if you have some other non-password authentication system in place, I believe you can use `ssh-copy-id` to copy a ssh identity to the server.  In the `ssh-copy-id` manual page it says:

> ssh-copy-id is a script that uses ssh
>   to  log  into  a  remote  machine
>   (presumably  using  a login password,
>   so password authentication should be
>   enabled, unless you've done some
>   clever use of multiple identities)

`ssh-copy-id` uses `ssh` to log into the remote machine, so if you can currently log into the machine, you can use `ssh-copy-id`.  If you can not log into the machine, then you can not use `ssh-copy-id`.  New id's will be appended to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 4):

Just tried it, and it doesn't look like it's possible.

Confirm that we have passwordless SSH access:

```
ssh root@redmine -- 'whoami'
#    root
```

The secondary public key I want to install

```
ls amir*
#    amir.pub
```

Attempt #1:

```
ssh-copy-id -i amir.pub root@redmine
#    ERROR: failed to open ID file './amir': No such file or directory
```

This has been reported as [OpenSSH bug #2110](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2110).

Workaround:  create a fake private key

```
touch amir

ssh-copy-id -i amir.pub root@redmine
#    INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
#    INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
#    root@redmine's password:
```

Looks like it's refusing to use the existing key in this case, unless I'm missing something.